# MacBook Pro 16" runs about 10 degrees hotter when plugged in on idle, is this normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

The degrees delta has a noticable impact on fan noise and is making me consider returning the machine.

Is it normal for MacBook to be running so much hotter when plugged in? Idles at 60 degrees on a charger and just 50 on battery.

Comment: I am going to assume you take your measure when the charging itself is idle. If you’re both running on AC power and charging, this is even more expected than I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Macbook Pro 16" has problems with external displays connected to it, sometimes even just external hdd's or other thunderbolt devices.

Do you have external displays connected?

Basically the GPU will get pinned at 18watt+ and produce max heat on the right side of the laptop where it is located.
This will cause the laptop to go at 60 degrees C at idle and 3k~ rpm fans, and spike to 100+ degrees under CPU load.

Apple has not responded officially to this, even though I am in multiple forums that have people mentioning they contact Apple support that have them go trough random tests that does nothing.
Please call Apple and report this issue so we get as many people reporting it as possible.
I have scheduled calls with them, that they keep postponing.

If you want to see for yourself istat menus can show you the information, it should have a trial so you can see it.

Short video of me having laptop unplugged and plugged with istat menus open:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3vV1-CWMQg

I have installed Turbo Boost Switcher, and turned off Turbo Boost for the time being or my Macbook will go into thermal shutdown on intense cpu tasks. 
Yay for getting an i9 cpu locked to 2.4Ghz the performance is terrible. 
Hoping Apple will eventually let me return it for money back, I'm over my no questions asked return days.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought I was going cray with @bmike insisting it was normal. Looks like we found the same solution to disable turbo boost in the interim until apple works out and fixes their thermal issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check "activity monitor" for CPU-usage.

You may have a busy webpage somewhere hidden on a tab in Chrome or Safari, using as much CPU as it can (and being allowed to as the machine is not on battery).

Comment: sadly no I did the test on idle in a fresh start up for both

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving this issue by installing Macs Fan Control app and setting the fan speed myself to 3000.

At idle now the CPU is at 65 degrees average at 3000RPM, without this the CPU would be at 60 degrees at 5500RPM. Fair trade until Apple figures out its thermal issues, this is almost certainly a bug in their thermal management (potentially a turboboost feedback loop?).

My workload requires bursts of performance (compiling code, etc) and I typically like to have a youtube video playing in the background, and now I can do both with the CPU turboboosting for short periods and 4k videos playing without having to turn the volume up to drown out the sounds of the fans going nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very normal to me. The 16  is designed to drive massive GPU and CPU wattage for maximum performance as opposed to maximum thermal economy. It’s the polar opposite of the MacBook One / iPad Pro design.

This is almost certainly the design since Apple controls the thermal and power envelopes strictly when on and off charger. I would avoid the delay of a return by getting a system scan remotely via AppleCare and then ask if they think it’s worth an exchange. Your MacBook Pro is designed to run for hours and days with the cpu at or near 100C. It’s designed to detect any reason to accelerate and push more pixels at a higher refresh rate or juice the CPU to run a benchmark fractionally faster than before.  A small difference at low power makes great sense to be the baseline settings for a lightly loaded system idling.

I expect we will see more control soon than we have today as well to both suppress wattage and engage it even earlier than you are seeing.

If you want a cool, low power unit, this isn’t the Mac designed for you.

- https://marco.org/2020/01/13/macos-low-power-mode-redux

Comment: The problem is that extra 10 degrees baseline is affecting the upper level wher eit's coming to a boil very very quickly and the fans are blasting at crazy high levels.

Other laptops are also designed to be running at hot temperatures but I haven't had these sorts of thermal issues on them, I feel like there's something wrong with this.

Comment: Trust your instinct / feelings and engage support, @meds. Boil is 100c not 60c but you’ll never be happy with it until this is resolved in you mind.

Comment: 60 is fine if it maintains it but because that's the new baseline it hits 100 much faster than when not plugged in, causing the fan to turn into a jet engine and stay there.

Comment: for example it just hit 100 degrees playing a single 1440p youtube video on an external monitor.

Comment: Yes. That’s what the maximum pro is designed to do. Sounds like you want an iPad Pro and not MacBook Pro based on your thermal management expectations.

Comment: The power draw required to run a 1440p youtube video should not push the cpu up to 100 degrees celsius with the fans on full blast.

Comment: looks like this is a super common issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250878229?answerId=252079325022&page=1 hopefully Apple fixes it instead of make more excuses.

Comment: @meds I don't disagree it runs warm when connected to a large external. I think Apple intended it and all units will behave this way. So it should be 100% of the units that behave this way so we're in agreement on how common this is. Time will tell if Apple decides to dial down the heat / performance when it could be needed and  people feel it's not or if they designed this to power up to run at high refresh rates when external displays are connected. Or if they say - get an EGPU if you don't want the MBP GPU/CPU doing the work.